# SurfaceView drawing paint with alpha color

Tags: android, animation, android-canvas, surfaceview, alpha

I have a `SurfaceView` where I'm running an animation using a basic `Thread` and `Canvas` set up. I've noticed a strange thing when I'm trying to perform a *fade* animation by simply decreasing the alpha on the `Paint` from 0x22 (34) to 0x00 (0). When the animation runs, it seems as if the rectangle doesn't fade smoothly; instead it appears to *skip* alpha levels. I know that it doesn't have any to do with my frame rate because I'm running it at a measured 60 FPS. Thinking it was related to how I implemented, I had the canvas draw out a strip of white rectangles with decreasing alpha. This is what I get...

[image]

The image is drawn with this code:

```
private void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

    Paint w = new Paint();
    w.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    Paint r = new Paint();
    r.setColor(Color.RED);
    r.setStrokeWidth(1.0f);

    for(int i = 0x22; i >= 0; i--) {
        w.setAlpha(i);
        int y = (0x22 - i) * 50;
        canvas.drawRect(0, y, 100, y + 50, w);
        canvas.drawLine(100, y, 110, y, r);
    }
}
```

It may be hard to see, but it looks as if the alpha decreases in blocks and not smoothly. You can tell that the red lines demark a new rectangle but the alpha doesn't seem to decrease appropriately. I'm suspecting that this is the reason why the alpha animation does not look smooth even when I'm running at 60 FPS. Has anyone experienced this before and/or know how I can get a smooth alpha animation with a `Canvas` on a `SurfaceView`?

Comment: Are you using pre-multiplied alpha colors?

Comment: Sorry but what does per-multiplied alpha colors mean? Everything I'm drawing on the `Canvas` is shown the code snippet above.

Comment: The default pixel format for a SurfaceView is RGB 565.  Did you call `mSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)` ?

Comment: Wow... that did it! Thanks so much! You should post this as an answer and I'll absolutely accept it!

Comment: Done.  FWIW, the pre-multiplied alpha concerns were with regard to the actual color values -- RGBA {128,128,128,128} is full-white with 50% transparency in one configuration, 50% grey with 50% transparency in the other.  So my first thought was that the color values weren't coming out right, but when I re-read your question I realized it was probably a color depth issue.

Comment: Interesting... I'm surprised I wasn't able to find someone with the same issue earlier. But thank you once again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `mSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)` to set the surface format to RGBA 8888.  Otherwise you get the default format, which is RGB 565.